# Black screen when trying to boot 16.04 with UNetbootin

Tags: 16.04, live-usb, unetbootin

I created a live USB using UNetbootin and when I boot from the USB I get the options to install, try, etc., but if I select one I get a black screen and nothing happens. I've tried editing the command with `nomodeset` but the same thing happens. I haven't installed any other OSs, but I want to dual boot, I've just done a fresh install of Windows 10.

My laptop is UEFI,  i7 5500U, 8GB RAM and NVIDIA 920m graphics.

Comment: Do you have any video options in the UEFI/BIOS settings like "integrated", "discrete", or optimized?  Try "integrated" first, that's Intel, and add the Nvidia proprietary drivers later.

Comment: No, I couldn't find any video settings in my BIOS or UEFI menus